# «Quiero que te dejes querer»: ¿a quién?

Tags: pronombres, sintaxis, letras-de-canciones

> I’m addicted to you 
>  Porque es un vicio tu piel 
>  Baby I’m addicted to you 
>  **Quiero que te dejes querer**
>
> <sub>— Shakira, “I’m Addicted to You,” *Sale el Sol*</sub>

Esta letra me confunde. Tengo entendido que el sujeto de la oración es Shakira su mismo y que se dirige a una pareja romántica. Me parecen posibles dos estructuras de la oración:

1. Ésta es un ejemplo del usar pronombres reflexivos para indicar la voz pasiva. Shakira quiere que el hombre permite que él sea querido. Pero eso me suena raro; no me parece que esta letra sea equivalente a «Quiero que te dejes quererte» ni «Quiero que te dejes ser querido».
2. El verbo *querer* simplemente es intransitivo y Shakira quiere que el hombre se permite amar en general.

¿Cuál es el sentido correcto de esa frase?

Comment: Literally: I want that you let yourself be loved.  Figuratively: Allow yourself to be loved.  Es la voz pasiva, *dejarse querer*, *dejarse rascar*, *dejarse ayudar*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we added pronouns for clarity this would be

> (Yo) Quiero que (tú) te dejes querer (**por mi**)

Which basically means "déjame amarte/let **me** love you". That `te` is a second person pronoun, so it refers to the man.

Pronouns wouldn't actually change if you meant "I want you to let people love you"

> (Yo) Quiero que (tú) te dejes querer (**por la gente**)

You could also say

> (Yo) Quiero que (tú) **me** dejes querer**te**

`Me`, first person pronoun would refer to Shakira and the second person `te` would refer to her lover.

Neither "Quiero que **te** dejes querer**te**" nor "Quiero que te dejes ser querido" apply.

If you meant "I want you to let people love you" you would say

> Quiero que (tú) te dejes **querer**

Using infinitive.

Ad notice the redundant pronouns in "Quiero que **te** dejes querer**te**". Again, infinitive is enough. That second pronoun is reduntant.